# javascript jquery ajax return object on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's a simple ajax call wrapped in a method.

```
MyNS.GetStringList = function (successCallback, failedCallback) {
var methodUrl = serverUrl + "/GetStringList";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: methodUrl, // Location of the service
    data: {}, //Data sent to server
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //ensures the results will be returned as JSON.
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: successCallback,
    error: failedCallback
});
}
```

Here's a method calling the above method.

```
function GoGetTheStringList() {
        var stringList;
        stringList = MyNS.GetStringList(function (data) { return data.d; }, function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        });

        alert(reasonsDictionary); // THIS IS UNDEFINED!

    }
```

What's the proper syntax to make the 1st method return the data.d object?

Thanks as always!
Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't really. Ajax calls are asynchronous, which means the method will have returned before  the `success` callback is invoked.

**EDIT / Correction:** You may be able do it, but you will have to set the jQuery ajax `async` option to `false`, which means you will be performing a synchronous call, which means your whole app will be waiting for it to return. It's best if you pass a callback to your function to be called when `success` is invoked.

**In response to your edit:** Yes, it will be undefined, because it is out of context. What you need to do is process your data from inside the callback, because at that point you will know you have it, and because you can't return data as a result of function A from function B. In your callback you should invoke a function to handle the data you got.

```
var latestData;
function getStuff(succeeded,failed) {...}
function gotStuff(dataWrapper) {
    latestData = dataWrapper.d;
    doThingsWithStuffData(dataWrapper.d);
}

getStuff(gotStuff, function () { ... });
```

Comment: Since my 1st method doesn't have a return statement, nothing gets returned. Adding the return statement in the success method doesn't work either. If I add a return in front of the $.ajax call I get the jhqr object which has the responseText property but not sure how safe it is to do that since it may not have returned yet.

Comment: Sorry. I completely misunderstood your point at first. I understand that you can't return from an async call. So, is there a way to pass a value type by reference so I don't have to put my logic in that call?

Comment: You don't need to put your logic there. If you check my reply you'll see that I invoke another function inside the callback to handle my data, after unwrapping it. As an aside, technically all object parameters are passed by reference in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the example and this does make perfect sense. However I need to post a new question on how to pass a value-type by reference in javascript since the logic I wan't to happen is to simply get the data.d object out of the success method and pass it to other methods possibly. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) as it is better suited for this purpose.

```
MyNS.GetStringList = function () {
var methodUrl = serverUrl + "/GetStringList";
return $.ajax({                            // return here, this will returns a deffered object
          type: "GET",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          url: methodUrl, // Location of the service
          data: {} //Data sent to server
       });
}
```

You shouldn't need to do

```
beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            //ensures the results will be returned as JSON.
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           },
```

That's what the `dataType: 'json'` does, it gives jQuery a hint as to what to expect in the response from the server.

Then in your function

```
function GoGetTheStringList() {
      var stringList;
      $.when( MyNS.GetStringList() )   
      .done(function( data ){  console.log( data.d );  }); 
      .fail(function( data ) { console.log('Request failed'); });
}
```